# Filter near by location product collection -magento2

Tags: magento2, locations, magento2.0.8, google-map

I have thousands of property in my store. I'm trying to write automated related properties. Each property has **latitude** and **longitude**. When customer click anyone property, we need to suggest five top most near by properties as related properties we have.

I found a way to get nearest product by using below mysql query

```
    SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

But it hard to convert as **search criteria** or **apply filter to product collectionFactory**

Testing controller

```
<?php

namespace Bilal\Test\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $jsonHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility


    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteria = $criteria;
        $this->filterGroup = $filterGroup;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {


        //Main Product Collection
        $target=$this->productRepository->getById(501);
        $lat =(float) $target->getCustomAttribute('c_lat')->getValue();
        $long =(float)$target->getCustomAttribute('c_long')->getValue();

        // Suggestde Near By Products Using Above Lat Long
        // Below one is return full product collection but I need to apply the above MYSQL query logic here
        $this->filterGroup->setFilters([
            $this->filterBuilder
                ->setField('status')
                ->setConditionType('in')
                ->setValue($this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds())
                ->create(),
            $this->filterBuilder
                ->setField('visibility')
                ->setConditionType('in')
                ->setValue($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
                ->create(),
        ]);

        $this->searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$this->filterGroup]);
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($this->searchCriteria);
        $productItems = $products->getItems();

        Return $productItems;

    }


}
```

Comment: http://assemblysys.com/geographical-distance-calculation-in-php/

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.2 (develop branch on github) you can use `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\CustomFilterInterface` for applying custom filter using product collection.

In your case, i think, that you need to create your custom service, which will be incapsulate working with product collection and with low-level `Magento\Framework\DB\Select` object for applying `distance` condition.

*Example:*

```
/**
 * Class ProductLocation.
 */
class ProductLocation extends ProductLocationInterface
{
    //constructor

    /**
     * Get nearby products.
     *
     * @param PointInterface $from
     * @param float $distance
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getNearbyProducts(PointInterface $from, $distance)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

        $productCollection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
            'distance',
            (string)$this->getDistanceExpression($from->getLatitude(), $from->getLongitude()),
            ['c_lat', 'c_lon']
        );

        $productCollection->getSelect()->having(
            $productCollection->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition(
                'distance',
                ['lt' => $distance]
            )
        );

        $productCollection->setOrder('distance');

        return $productCollection->getLoadedIds();
    }

    /**
     * Get distance expression.
     *
     * @param float $latitude
     * @param float $longitude
     * @return \Zend_Db_Expr
     */
    private function getDistanceExpression($latitude, $longitude)
    {
        return new \Zend_Db_Expr("
            SQRT(
                POW(69.1 * ({{c_lat}} - {$latitude}), 2) +
                POW(69.1 * ({$longitude} - {{c_lon}}) * COS({{c_lat}} / 57.3), 2)
            )
        ");
    }
}
```

> Note, that this is example, you need to take care about SQL-injection
>   protections and refactor this code for prevent hardcoded variables.

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php on line 565
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php on line 565
Call Stack
Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor->addExpressionAttributeToSelect( ) .../autorelated.php:20
3 0.6565  Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor->addExpressionAttributeToSelect( ) .../Interceptor.php:934